# find record from referenced tables of primary key column

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-server-2012

I am stuck in a sql query where I have to find a record which exist in any of referenced table. i.e.

Primary table : A, column is a_id

Foreign tables : B, C, D in which a_id is a foreign key null-able column and In these tables records may contains value of a_id or null value.

So I want to create a query which return data if a_id exist in any one of referencing table.

I was tried with left join but it always return 1 record as I am selecting record from A table.

Please see this:

```
select * from A tp
left join B altl on tp.a_id = altl.a_id
left join C sd on tp.a_id = sd.a_id 
left join D st on tp.a_id = st.a_id where tp.a_id = 46
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select <columns>
from B
where a_id = 46
union all
select <columns>
from C
where a_id = 46
union all
select <columns>
from D
where a_id = 46
```

You don't need table A in your query, you just need the value you are interested in, also, your list of columns has to be the same for each query in the UNION or you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks MJH :), Can we write this in Linq as well?

Comment: No problem, I am converting this into Linq.